# CoordinatorLayout + scrollFlags in fragments not properly hiding menu and breaking other fragments when it does, FAB gets lost when scrolling too

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button, android-appbarlayout

I've started a new project.  I'd read that single Activity, and a number of fragments was a common recommended approach.  I have a MainActivity, and 3 fragments.  This setup is just from the "Basic Project" template in the lastest Android Studio.

My goal is to have the AppBar hide itself on one of the fragments when scrolling down as is very common with apps in addition to the FAB displaying properly when doing that and moving up when a Snackbar shows up.  My CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout>Toolbar are in the MainActivity, while the FAB and Recycler are in a fragment.

In the process of working on this I've managed to make the AppBar either cover up the top of the page and/or the bottom of the page being too low and cutting off stuff.  These are my views (shortened for brevity):

main_activity

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <AppBarLayout android:theme="@style/Theme.DynamicGPTChat.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.DynamicGPTChat.PopupOverlay" />
    </AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <!-- a floating action button here does work, but all the scroll issues still persist.
         the only page it's needed on has a click listener -->
    <!-- com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton -->
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_scroll

```xml
<ConstraintLayout>

    <RecyclerView />
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_input

```xml
<ConstraintLayout>
    <RecyclerView />

    <TextInputLayout app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        <TextInputEditText />
    </TextInputLayout>

    <MaterialButton app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/prompt_input_layout" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/prompt_input_layout" />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

If I add `layout_scrollFlags` to the AppBarLayout, then `fragment_scroll` works mostly.  The FAB doesn't react right and it sinks down till I can just see the top bit as I scroll down.  But the fragment_input the item constrained to the bottom is below the bottom so I can only see the top bit, and on the last fragment which is just a bunch of inputs, the bottom item isn't visible anymore.  I'm pretty sure this is because the way it does the hiding of the AppBar is making the page a little bit taller.

I tried removing the `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` on the Coordinator layout, but then the AppBar covers the pages.  I tried moving the behavior to the root node in the fragments, I tried the scrollFrags on different nodes in the fragments.  I tried wrapping the fragments with CoordinatedLayout.

The FAB doesn't move up for Snackbars either, and none of that helped.  I was just going to move the FAB to the activity view and then hide it for everything and use an event listener with my SharedViewModel for the click on the one page it's needed, but then I noticed the AppBar scrolling issues and that's not as simple to fix.  I thought this was all supposed to be basic built in stuff.  Is there something easy I'm missing?  I could really use some help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would still love an answer.  Am I supposed to just have an AppBar/Toolbar & CordinatorLayout for every single page/fragment?

My solution is simply a workaround:

SharedViewModel

```java
val onFabClick: MutableLiveData<(() -> Unit)?> = MutableLiveData(null)
```

Fragment

```java
sharedViewModel.onFabClick.value = { this.localMethod() }
```

MainActivity

```java
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val fab = binding.floatingActionButton
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.ListFragment -> {
                    fab.show()
                    updateAppBarScrollFlags(true)
                }
                else -> {
                    fab.hide()
                    updateAppBarScrollFlags(false)
                }
            }
        }
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            //this enables the FAB to be clicked and trigger a method that can be assigned in any Fragment
            sharedViewModel.onFabClick.value?.invoke()
        }

}
    private fun updateAppBarScrollFlags(isScrollEnabled: Boolean) {
        val toolbar = binding.toolbar
        val params = toolbar.layoutParams as AppBarLayout.LayoutParams
        if (isScrollEnabled) {
            params.scrollFlags = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL
                    or AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS
                    or AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP)
        } else {
            params.scrollFlags = 0
        }
        toolbar.layoutParams = params
    }
```